# Passing two arguments to replace function for Re.sub

Tags: python, regex

How can I pass two variables to my replace function?

I have defined it as

```
def replace(line,suppress)
```

Calling it like so:

```
line = re.sub(r'''(?x)
                    ([\\]*\$\*)|
                    ([\\]*\$\{[0-9]+\})|
                    ([\\]*\$[0-9]+)|
                    ([\\]*\$\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\-.*\})|
                    ([\\]*\$\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\=.*\})|
                    ([\\]*\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|
                    ([\\]*\$\{[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\})|
                    ([\\]*\$[\{]+.*)
                    ''',replace,line,suppress)
```

Receiving error:

```
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: replace() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what your trying?

Comment: I don't understand... You want to pass `re.sub` a method? It takes a pattern, replacement string for the matches, and a string to run the pattern against. Here's the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: Apollo needs to show more of his code if he wants help diagnosing his problem, but as the docs say, re.sub can take a function as an argument. I'm finding "suppress" quite confusing.

Answer (score 10):

As has been mentioned, when `re.sub` calls your function, it only passes one argument to it. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) indicate this is a match object (presumably the `line` variable?)

If you want to pass additional arguments, you should wrap your function up in a lambda expression.

So something like:

```
re.sub('...', lambda line: replace(line, suppress))
```

or

```
re.sub('...', lambda line, suppress=suppress: replace(line, suppress))
```

Note the use of `suppress=suppress` in the signature of the second `lambda`. This is there to ensure the value of `suppress` used is the value of `suppress` when the `lambda` was **defined**. Without that, the value of `suppress` used is the value of `suppress` when the function is executed. In this case, it actually wouldn't matter (as the lambda is used immediately after definition, so `suppress` will never be changed between definition and execution), but I think it's important you understand how `lambda` works for using it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`Re.sub` only accepts function for its `repl` argument which take one value.  That's defined in the implementation of `Re.sub`.  You don't have access to it.