# How to pass two arguments to a user defined function in Python's re.sub function?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I pass two arguments to my user defined function `add_year` in Python's `re.sub()` function?

input

```
text = re.sub(r'(DEC \d{2})|(JAN \d{2})', add_year(statement_year_from, statement_year_to), text) # this is what I want to accomplish
```

expected output

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='DEC 15'> 2022 2023
<re.Match object; span=(7, 13), match='JAN 03'> 2022 2023
```

Moderators, please free to delete the question if you feel it does not add any value to the discussion. While composing the question, I was able to resolve the problem.

Happy to receive any constructive feedback with regards to the approach or the solution.

Existing method and call

```
def add_year(match_obj):
    if match_obj.group(1) is not None:
        print(match_obj.group(), statement_year_from, 'statement_year_from')
        return match_obj.group(1) + " " + statement_year_from
    if match_obj.group(2) is not None:
        print(match_obj.group(), statement_year_to, 'statement_year_to')
        return match_obj.group(2) + " " + statement_year_to
```

calling `add_year`

```
text = 'DEC 15 JAN 03 2022 PAYMENT - THANK YOU -$100.99'
statement_year = 'STATEMENT FROM DEC 06, 2022 TO JAN 03, 2023'
words = statement_year.split(' ')
statement_year_from = words[4] # get DEC year
statement_year_to = words[8] # get JAN year

print(statement_year_from, statement_year_to)

print(text)
text = re.sub(r'(DEC \d{2})|(JAN \d{2})', add_year, text)
# text = re.sub(r'(DEC \d{2})|(JAN \d{2})', add_year(statement_year_from, statement_year_to), text) # this is what I want to accomplish
print(text)
```

In summary, convert

```
text = re.sub(r'(DEC \d{2})|(JAN \d{2})', add_year, text)
```

to

```
text = re.sub(r'(DEC \d{2})|(JAN \d{2})', add_year(statement_year_from, statement_year_to, match_obj), text)
```

My attemp to understand and come up with a solution

- Reviewed [Passing two arguments to replace function for Re.sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496119/passing-two-arguments-to-replace-function-for-re-sub). Unfortunatley because of my limited coding skills, I am not able to "translate" the reply to my need, sorry.
- Took a look at `lambda` functions using [Python LAMBDA Functions Explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ob9rY6PQMfI)
- To simply the issue, updated the `add_year` function and call as follows

---

updated function `add_year`

```
def add_year(match_obj):
   print(match_obj)
```

updated function call to `re.sub()`

```
# only the updated line
text = re.sub(r'(DEC \d{2})|(JAN \d{2})', lambda statement_year_from: add_year(statement_year_from), text)
```

`output`

```
# output was a surprise. Instead of showing the value of statement_year_from,
# the values of matched groups are displayed
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='DEC 15'>
<re.Match object; span=(7, 13), match='JAN 03'>
```

---

Attempts # 2

updated function `add_year`

```
def add_year(match_obj, statement_year_from):
    print(match_obj)
```

updated function call to `re.sub()`

```
# only the updated line
text = re.sub(r'(DEC \d{2})|(JAN \d{2})', lambda match_obj, statement_year_from: add_year(match_obj, statement_year_from), text)
```

`error`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[42], line 10
      5 statement_year_to = words[8] # get JAN year
      7 # print(statement_year_from, statement_year_to)
      8 
      9 # print(text)
---> 10 text = re.sub(r'(DEC \d{2})|(JAN \d{2})', lambda match_obj, statement_year_from: add_year(match_obj, statement_year_from), text)
     11 # print(text)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\re\__init__.py:186, in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    179 def sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):
    180     """Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
    181     non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
    182     replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
    183     if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
    184     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
    185     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 186     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)

TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'statement_year_from'
```

fixed the error by updating the call as follows

```
text = re.sub(r'(DEC \d{2})|(JAN \d{2})', lambda match_obj, statement_year_from=statement_year_from: add_year(match_obj, statement_year_from), text)
```

`output`

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='DEC 15'> 2022 2023
<re.Match object; span=(7, 13), match='JAN 03'> 2022 2023
```

final version of the code that works

```
def add_year(match_obj, statement_year_from, statement_year_to):
    print(match_obj, statement_year_from, statement_year_to)

# main function    
text = 'DEC 15 JAN 03 2022 PAYMENT - THANK YOU -$100.99'
    statement_year = 'STATEMENT FROM DEC 06, 2022 TO JAN 03, 2023'
    words = statement_year.split(' ')
    statement_year_from = words[4] # get DEC year
    statement_year_to = words[8] # get JAN year

text = re.sub(r'(DEC \d{2})|(JAN \d{2})', lambda match_obj, statement_year_from=statement_year_from, statement_year_to=statement_year_to: add_year(match_obj, statement_year_from, statement_year_to), text)

# output    
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='DEC 15'> 2022 2023
<re.Match object; span=(7, 13), match='JAN 03'> 2022 2023
```

Comment: The question is a bit long winded. Can you summarize it with a clarification of the _input text_ , and the _expected output text_?

Comment: Hi @wim, sorry for being long winded. I was able to resolve the issue and asked the question in the hope that the long winded question and short answer will help someone in the future. Let me try and add a short sumary at the beginning of the question.